# Add the contents of a ZIP file to another folder in the same ZIP file

Tags: java, filesystems

I have a zip file say 'abc.zip' which has two folders in it say 'f1' and 'f2'. These folders also have many files/folders inside it.
I want to create one folder say 'internal' inside 'abc.zip' and move all the contents of 'abc.zip' to this internal folder, without extracting the zip.
So, my final output will be, 'abc.zip' having 'internal' folder. And 'internal' will have the folders 'f1' and f2'

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This operation in any case will involve zip extraction

Comment: If I have a ZIP containing huge data (30GBs), then this operation takes lot of time in extracting and packing the zip again. I want some efficient solution to this.

Comment: Such is the struggle of huge data

Comment: I tried using Zip File System Provider, and I am able to create a new folder inside existing zip.However, I am not able to move the contents of existing zip to this folder. I referred http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: @SheetalBhatewara Please provide your sample code and tell us where exactly you had issues.

Comment: ZIP format was not designed for such file operations, so any re-arrangment of files in the ZIP archive in most cases would require complete rewrite of the archive. If your file operations are frequent, you might want to look at some other container format.